# Table with rows of different colors with tableGrob

Tags: r

I want to make a table with `tableGrob` function and I also want to complete rows put color but to specific rows. h.even.alpha, h.odd.alpha, v.even.alpha and v.odd.alpha are for 2 colors interspersed and not work in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want differing shades on the same colour (or alternating with white), you can use `h.even.alpha` and `h.odd.alpha` (and `v.even.alpha`/`v.odd.alpha`)

```
library(gridExtra)

grid.table(head(iris), h.even.alpha = 1, h.odd.alpha = 0, 
   v.even.alpha = 1, v.odd.alpha = 1)
```

[image]

If you want completely different colours, you can draw the table twice, with different settings for `gpar.corefill` (and the corresponding `alpha` values)

```
grid.newpage()
grid.table(head(iris), h.even.alpha = 1, h.odd.alpha = 0, 
   v.even.alpha = 1, v.odd.alpha = 1, 
   gpar.corefill = gpar(fill = 'red',col = 'white'))
 grid.table(head(iris), h.even.alpha = 0, h.odd.alpha = 1, 
   v.even.alpha = 1, v.odd.alpha = 1, 
   gpar.corefill = gpar(fill = 'purple',col = 'white'))
```

[image]