# gridExtra Colour different rows with tableGrob

Tags: r, gridextra

I have a question regarding tableGrob/grid.table from the gridExtra package.  Using the regular parameter settings, it is straightforward to colour alternate rows. However, I was hoping that it might be feasible to get a bit more control over the colouring of the rows.

For example, is it possible to colour every *third* row in a different colour?
I suspect the grid.edit function is one way to approach this, judging by the example in this link: http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob but I can't figure out how to apply that to my question.

I believe the person who posted this question had the same in mind. [Table with rows of different colors with tableGrob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756052/table-with-rows-of-different-colors-with-tablegrob)

I am currently stuck with R 2.13 due to compatibility issues, so if there are any suggestions which don't involve later versions that would be ideal.

Example code:

```
library(gridExtra)

grid.table(mtcars[1:10, ],
           gpar.coretext = gpar(fontsize = 10),
           gpar.corefill = gpar(fill = "lightblue", alpha=0.5, col = NA),
           h.even.alpha = 0.5
           )
```

[image: example table]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and well done for referencing other questions in your own to show that you've done some work on your own. May I suggest that in future questions you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), either using your own data, 'fake' data or a built-in such as the `mtcars` data set. Simple, indeed minimal, is best (I have added one to yours), just enough to allow others to copy, paste and experiment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

starting with v>=2.0.0 of gridExtra, `grid.table` is now based on gtable, and can be customised to deeper levels than in previous versions. The [vignette has more examples](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob), but for completeness here is an example illustrating how to highlight specific cells,

```
g <- tableGrob(iris[1:4, 1:3])
find_cell <- function(table, row, col, name="core-fg"){
  l <- table$layout
  which(l$t==row & l$l==col & l$name==name)
}

ind <- find_cell(g, 3, 2, "core-fg")
ind2 <- find_cell(g, 2, 3, "core-bg")
g$grobs[ind][[1]][["gp"]] <- gpar(fontsize=15, fontface="bold")
g$grobs[ind2][[1]][["gp"]] <- gpar(fill="darkolivegreen1", col = "darkolivegreen4", lwd=5)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

*Edit: the above function is easily "vectorised"*

```
find_cells <- function(table, row, col, name="core-fg"){
  l <- table$layout
  unlist(Map(function(r, c) which(((l$t-1) == r) & ((l$l-1) == c) & (l$name == name)), row, col))
}

modify_cells <- function(g, ids, gp=gpar()){
  for(id in ids) g$grobs[id][[1]][["gp"]] <- gp
  return(g)
}

ids <- find_cells(g, 1:3, c(3,2, 1), "core-fg")
g <- modify_cells(g, ids, gpar(fontsize=15, fontface="bold"))

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Note that in most cases it would make more sense to specify the parameters during the table construction,

```
faces <- sample(1:4, size = prod(dim(iris[1:4, 1:2])), replace = TRUE)
tt <- ttheme_default(core=list(fg_params=list(fontface=faces)))

grid.table(iris[1:4, 1:2], theme=tt)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know if somebody is still listening here, but I'll try anyway: is it possible to tweak the find_cell function such that it finds several different cells at once and not just one by one? For instance, all Sepal.Length >4.8 get written in bold. I have a tableGrob with statistical significance testing and I  need all pvalues < 0.05 to be bold. It would be good to have this in one function rather than manually doing it for each cell. thanks

Comment: What does the name ""core-fg" mean/do?

Comment: the table is divided into 3 parts: column header, row header, and core cells (body). Each of those has two "layers": a background rectangle (grey here for the core, darker for the column header), and a foreground ("fg") for the text.